# How do I add an image filter only in the touch radius in swift

Tags: image, swift, filter, touch

I am new to swift and I have an app which allows the user to get a picture from their camera roll and display it in an imageview. I have found plenty of tutorials on how to add filters, but how do I isolate this to a touch radius, not the entire image?

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import Social
import MobileCoreServices
import MessageUI
import iAd

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,                UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate,     UITextViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!

let picker = UIImagePickerController()
var cameraUI: UIImagePickerController! = UIImagePickerController()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

@IBAction func filter(sender: UIButton) {

    let myPicture = imageView.image

    let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIPhotoEffectMono")

    filter.setValue(CIImage(image: myPicture), forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
    let newImage = UIImage(CIImage: filter.outputImage)

    imageView.image = newImage


}



override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    let myPicture = imageView.image
    for obj in touches {
        let touch = obj as! UITouch
        let location = touch.locationInView(self.view)
    }

}

@IBAction func getImageButton(sender: UIButton) {


    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary)
    {
        cameraUI = UIImagePickerController()
        cameraUI.delegate = self
        cameraUI.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary;
        cameraUI.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeImage]
        cameraUI.allowsEditing = false

        self.presentViewController(cameraUI, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    else
    {
        let alertVC = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Cannot open camera roll.", preferredStyle: .Alert)
        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style:.Default, handler: nil)
        alertVC.addAction(okAction)
        presentViewController(alertVC, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

       }


func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    var chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage //2
    imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit //3
    imageView.image = chosenImage //4
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil) //5
}

func noCamera(){
    let alertVC = UIAlertController(title: "No Camera", message: "Sorry, this device has no camera", preferredStyle: .Alert)
    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style:.Default, handler: nil)
    alertVC.addAction(okAction)
    presentViewController(alertVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}


func savedImageAlert()
{
    var alert:UIAlertView = UIAlertView()
    alert.title = "Saved!"
    alert.message = "Your picture was saved"
    alert.delegate = self
    alert.addButtonWithTitle("Ok")
    alert.show()
}
}
```

Comment: Please be more specific — what techniques are you using so far? What have you tried / where are you stuck?

Comment: I would like to essentially draw over an image in an imageview, but I would like a filter instead of a solid line (i.e. a blur or black and white) then allow the  user to save the edited image. I hope this clears it up a bit. I will add my code below